# WordPress Custom Post Type Posts Showing in All Categories

Tags: wordpress, post, types

I am using the below code in my `loop.php` file to display custom post types. In my loop file, there are 2 loops, the first loop is for general post type post and second loop is for custom post type. In custom post type I am using the same categories as with general post type.

I created my custom post type and saved in `mycategory`. When I see `mycategory` page, these posts are displayed but when I visit other category pages, these custom posts are also displayed. Why this custom post type is appearing in all category while just created it in `mycategory`.

I have used many codes from forums, tutorials to specify the category but still displaying posts in all categories.

I want to display custom post type only in category in which I saved the post.

```
$args = array('showposts'=>25, 'category' => 'Mycategory' ,'post_type'=>'Jobs');
```

Comment: You're going to need to modify the query for the "all categories" page, and exclude your custom post type.

Comment: I am new to wordpress, can you please let me know how and where do i modify the query as you have told above.

Comment: It'll probably be in whatever template is being used to serve the "all categories" page. This is usually *archive.php*. You'll need to modify the query to exclude your post type, by adding something like the following to the query: `$query = new WP_Query( 'post_type=-Jobs' );`. Notice the minus symbol. Read more [in the docs on this subject](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Type_Parameters)

Comment: But i do not want to exclude the post type Jobs to appear in my categories page, I do want to display custom post type in category page, the only what i want is the post should only appear in what category that I saved the post in. The the post type job should not appear in all categories except to what i have saved the post in.